# Problem with request google sheets with Highcharts error 404

Tags: javascript, google-sheets, highcharts, google-sheets-api

I've been having problems with Highcharts when requesting from a google sheet, few days ago it was all good, but suddenly it was throwing an error 404, and I don't know what to do. Higcharts only ask you to put the google spreadsheet key, and the number of the tab, and nothing else. I want to change the URL that Higcharts makes the request but I don't know how.
Error:

```
data.src.js:124 GET https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/cells/1YtSfF3-9kzx1G6zwllLX9GhkVgufSUjQyKVI3Ken-AA/2/public/values?alt=json 404
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try tu use this function to get values as json

```
function getJson(id,gid){
  var txt = UrlFetchApp.fetch(`https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/${id}/gviz/tq?tqx=out:json&tq&gid=${gid}`).getContentText();
  var jsonString = txt.match(/(?<="table":).*(?=}\);)/g)[0]
  var json = JSON.parse(jsonString)
  return(json)
}
```

- with id of the spreadsheet and gid of your sheet (may be 0)
- note that first row is dedicated to labels, then rows[0] corresponds to row#2 and c[0] corresponds to column A
- if you want to retrieve B1 (column 2 row 1) : `json.cols[1].label`
- if you want to retrieve B2 (column 2 row 2) : `json.rows[0].c[1].v`

Answer (score 2):

It seems like a google issue: https://support.google.com/docs/thread/121088347/retrieving-data-from-sheets-results-in-404-error-50-of-the-time

Answer (score 2):

feeds is the older version of Sheets API and it's shut down.
See Google's announcement here https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/g-suite/migrate-your-apps-use-latest-sheets-api